# Operational Error : unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, apache

Trying to deploy a `Django` app over `Apache` . Installed all dependencies, Apache is running fine , no errors, however when I launch the domain, It gives the error :

> Operational Error : unable to open database file

This is where the database is stored :

`/home/wger/db/database.sqlite`

And in order to make sure I have the permissions, I did :

```
chgrp www-data /home/wger/db/
chgrp www-data /home/wger/db/database.sqlite
chmod g+w /home/wger/db/
chmod g+w /home/wger/db/database.sqlite
chmod 664 /home/wger/db/database.sqlite
chmod 664 /home/wger/db
sudo chown :www-data /home/wger/db
sudo chown :www-data /home/wger/db/database.sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However, the issue still persist. what is possibly causing this and how to effectively resolve this ?

**PS** : *I tried existing answers to identical questions, however I was not able to resolve the error!*

Comment: You might need to `chmod 664 /home/wger` too, though it seems like you should probably move the DB file outside of your personal home directory if the app is going to be run by the www-data user.

Comment: @TomDalton So where would be the ideal place to keep the database directory ?  Also, If I move the database directory, should I choose to update the absoulute path in settings.py as well ?

Comment: In settings.py, under DATABASES, where does that point?

Comment: @Dalvtor in the databases section, `ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` and `'NAME': '/home/wger/db/database.sqlite'`

Comment: @TomDalton added chmod for /home/wger as well. however, now it says forbidden !

Comment: Your permissions should be `644` on the file and `755` on the directory.